# Get the territory / country belonging to a locale?

Tags: templating, localization

I'm asking, because I was trying to find out the whole afternoon. Found some posts, but they were related to getting all territories.

Example:

I have locales like English, French, Chinese and I'd like to add country to each related locale from territories, because each locale.php in /data folder has the values.

So it would looks like: Territory(United Kingdom) locale(English)

Code I'm working on:

```
{% set locale = craft.i18n.getCurrentLocale() %}
    {# Configure site locales #}
    {% set locales = ['en', 'en_gb', 'sk'] %}
    {# Check if locale equals the requested page locale #}
    {% if locale == craft.locale %}
        {% set current = true %}
    {% else %}
        {% set current = false %}
    {% endif %}

<ul>
  {% for locale in locales %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ craft.request.getPath() }}">
         ({{ craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).nativeName }})
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```

The output is a list of locales with native name:

- (English)
- (British English)
- (Slovak)

If there would be a way to relate it's country to each locale from territories, that we wouldn't have to touch app folder to customize the lang files, like I read in other posts.
By doing so, We could achieve this:

- World (English)
- United Kingdom (British English)
- Slovakia (Slovak)

**Update**

I think it moved on a little bit. With the code @carlcs provided, Craft was able to get a territory. There must to be some bug in it, because **from 3 locales, It got assigned to only one territory** (United Kingdom - British English).

Here is updated code.

```
 <ul class="uk-nav">
 {% set locales = ['en', 'en_gb', 'sk'] %}
   {% for locale in locales %}
      {% set subTags = locale|split('_') %}
         {% set territory = subTags|length > 1 ? craft.i18n.getLocaleData(craft.locale).getTerritory(subTags|last) : '' %}  
             <li>
                 <a href="{{ craft.config.siteUrl[locale] ~ craft.request.getPath() }}" class="{{ current ? 'uk-active'}}">
                 {% if territory %}{{ territory }}{% endif %} ({{craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).nativeName }})
                 </a>
             </li>
  {% endfor %} 
  </ul>
```

Comment: Dominic, could you please explain a bit on what you're trying to acchive?

Comment: Yeah... not sure I'm following, either.

Comment: That's easy, Dominic. No territory part in your locale →no territory!

Comment: @carlcs So I have to modify the files from ../i18n/data/locale.php? I'd like to avoid that if So.

Comment: No, use locales with territory subtags only! Example: locale `de` has no territory info (and could be spoken anywhere in the world), but `de_de` does have that secific info, it's german as it is spoken in germany. It's that simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a territory name directly from a locale tag (e.g. 'en' or 'en_gb'). But what you could do is to
take the territory part of the tag (two letter country code; **keep in mind, it's optional**) and get the territory
name via `getTerritory`:

```
{% set locales = ['en_gb', 'fr_fr', 'zh_cn'] %}

{% for locale in locales %}

    {% set subTags = locale|split('_') %}

    {% set territory = subTags|length > 1 ? craft.i18n.getLocaleData(craft.locale).getTerritory(subTags|last) : '' %}

    {% set language = craft.i18n.getLocaleById(locale).name %}
    {% set language = language ?: craft.i18n.getLocaleById(subTags|first).name %}
    {% set language = language|replace("/- #{territory}$/", '') %}

    {% if territory and language %}
        <li>Territory: {{ territory }}, Language: {{ language }}</li>
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey @carlcs, I got it tried with the code I updated the question with, but I always got only the same country, for all locales. You're right. There is no relation with locales and territories, so it's impossible yet. Thanks anyway

Comment: No @Dominic! There actually is a relationship between locals and territories, I think you misunderstood my answer. The code works as is, so you probably didn't implemented it correctly for your needs.

Comment: Finally I got to it and have started testing. Yes, it works, It's great, except regions `en_001` etc. I get empty value for `locale`.

Comment: @Dominik now you can go crazy and do things like 'en_001', 'hu_sk', 'de_sk' or 'tr_de'.

Comment: Love IT more! @carlcs Thank you, you good.